# RuntimeError: Unknown type bool encountered in graph lowering. This type is not supported in ONNX export

Tags: python, ios, pytorch, coremltools, torchscript

I am trying to convert the [Self-Correction-Human-Parsing](https://github.com/PeikeLi/Self-Correction-Human-Parsing) to coreml.
The issue that I am facing is also open on https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/52889
and https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/1085.

The evaluate.py file (for reference) looks like this (after some addition to convert model to coreml) :

```
import coremltools as ct
import os
import argparse
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils import data
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image as PILImage
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn

import networks
from datasets.datasets import LIPDataValSet
from utils.miou import compute_mean_ioU
from utils.transforms import BGR2RGB_transform
from utils.transforms import transform_parsing
import onnxruntime
import onnx

def get_arguments():
    """Parse all the arguments provided from the CLI.

    Returns:
      A list of parsed arguments.
    """
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Self Correction for Human Parsing")

    # Network Structure
    parser.add_argument("--arch", type=str, default='resnet101')
    # Data Preference
    parser.add_argument("--data-dir", type=str, default='./data/LIP')
    parser.add_argument("--batch-size", type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument("--input-size", type=str, default='473,473')
    parser.add_argument("--num-classes", type=int, default=20)
    parser.add_argument("--ignore-label", type=int, default=255)
    parser.add_argument("--random-mirror", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--random-scale", action="store_true")
    # Evaluation Preference
    parser.add_argument("--log-dir", type=str, default='./log')
    parser.add_argument("--model-restore", type=str, default='./log/checkpoint.pth.tar')
    parser.add_argument("--gpu", type=str, default='0', help="choose gpu device.")
    parser.add_argument("--save-results", action="store_true", help="whether to save the results.")
    parser.add_argument("--flip", action="store_true", help="random flip during the test.")
    parser.add_argument("--multi-scales", type=str, default='1', help="multiple scales during the test")
    return parser.parse_args()


def get_palette(num_cls):
    """ Returns the color map for visualizing the segmentation mask.
    Args:
        num_cls: Number of classes
    Returns:
        The color map
    """
    n = num_cls
    palette = [0] * (n * 3)
    for j in range(0, n):
        lab = j
        palette[j * 3 + 0] = 0
        palette[j * 3 + 1] = 0
        palette[j * 3 + 2] = 0
        i = 0
        while lab:
            palette[j * 3 + 0] |= (((lab >> 0) & 1) << (7 - i))
            palette[j * 3 + 1] |= (((lab >> 1) & 1) << (7 - i))
            palette[j * 3 + 2] |= (((lab >> 2) & 1) << (7 - i))
            i += 1
            lab >>= 3
    return palette


def multi_scale_testing(model, batch_input_im, crop_size=[473, 473], flip=True, multi_scales=[1]):
    flipped_idx = (15, 14, 17, 16, 19, 18)
    if len(batch_input_im.shape) > 4:
        batch_input_im = batch_input_im.squeeze()
    if len(batch_input_im.shape) == 3:
        batch_input_im = batch_input_im.unsqueeze(0)

    interp = torch.nn.Upsample(size=crop_size, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
    ms_outputs = []
    for s in multi_scales:
        interp_im = torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=s, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
        scaled_im = interp_im(batch_input_im)
        print("Scaled_im:",type(scaled_im),scaled_im.shape)
        # traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, scaled_im.to("cuda:0"))
        # parsing_output = model(scaled_im)
        scripted_model = torch.jit.script(model)

        print("Trying coreml part")
        core_model = ct.convert(scripted_model,inputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=scaled_im.shape)])
        core_model.save("human_parsing.mlmodel")
        print("human parsing model saved!")
        # torch.onnx.export(model,scaled_im.to("cuda:0"),"human_parsing.onnx",opset_version=11)
        # print("Loading onnx model...")
        
        # onnx_model = onnx.load("human_parsing.onnx")
        # onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
        # ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession("human_parsing.onnx")
        # def to_numpy(tensor):
        #     return tensor.detach().cpu().numpy() if tensor.requires_grad else tensor.cpu().numpy()
        # # x = torch.rand(1,3,473,473)
        # # ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: to_numpy(x)}
        # ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: to_numpy(scaled_im)}
        # parsing_output =  ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)
        # print("Parsing output 1:", len(parsing_output))

        parsing_output = parsing_output[0][-1]
        parsing_output = np.expand_dims(parsing_output,axis=0)
        parsing_output = torch.from_numpy(parsing_output)
        print("Parsing output 2:",parsing_output.shape)
        output = parsing_output[0]
        if flip:
            flipped_output = parsing_output[1]
            flipped_output[14:20, :, :] = flipped_output[flipped_idx, :, :]
            output += flipped_output.flip(dims=[-1])
            output *= 0.5

        print("output:", output)

        print("output:", output.shape)
        print("output Type:", type(output))
        output = interp(output.unsqueeze(0))
        print("output unsqueezed:", output.shape)

        ms_outputs.append(output[0])
    ms_fused_parsing_output = torch.stack(ms_outputs)
    ms_fused_parsing_output = ms_fused_parsing_output.mean(0)
    ms_fused_parsing_output = ms_fused_parsing_output.permute(1, 2, 0)  # HWC
    parsing = torch.argmax(ms_fused_parsing_output, dim=2)
    parsing = parsing.data.cpu().numpy()
    ms_fused_parsing_output = ms_fused_parsing_output.data.cpu().numpy()
    return parsing, ms_fused_parsing_output


def main():
    """Create the model and start the evaluation process."""
    args = get_arguments()
    multi_scales = [float(i) for i in args.multi_scales.split(',')]
    gpus = [int(i) for i in args.gpu.split(',')]
    assert len(gpus) == 1
    if not args.gpu == 'None':
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = args.gpu

    cudnn.benchmark = True
    cudnn.enabled = True

    h, w = map(int, args.input_size.split(','))
    input_size = [h, w]

    model = networks.init_model(args.arch, num_classes=args.num_classes, pretrained=None)

    IMAGE_MEAN = model.mean
    IMAGE_STD = model.std
    INPUT_SPACE = model.input_space
    print('image mean: {}'.format(IMAGE_MEAN))
    print('image std: {}'.format(IMAGE_STD))
    print('input space:{}'.format(INPUT_SPACE))
    if INPUT_SPACE == 'BGR':
        print('BGR Transformation')
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=IMAGE_MEAN,
                                 std=IMAGE_STD),

        ])
    if INPUT_SPACE == 'RGB':
        print('RGB Transformation')
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            BGR2RGB_transform(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=IMAGE_MEAN,
                                 std=IMAGE_STD),
        ])

    # Data loader
    lip_test_dataset = LIPDataValSet(args.data_dir, 'val', crop_size=input_size, transform=transform, flip=args.flip)
    num_samples = len(lip_test_dataset)
    print('Total testing sample numbers: {}'.format(num_samples))
    testloader = data.DataLoader(lip_test_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=False, pin_memory=True)
    # num_samples =1
    
    # Load model weight
    state_dict = torch.load(args.model_restore)['state_dict']
    from collections import OrderedDict
    new_state_dict = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in state_dict.items():
        name = k[7:]  # remove `module.`
        new_state_dict[name] = v
    model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
    model.cuda()
    model.eval()
    
    sp_results_dir = os.path.join(args.log_dir, 'sp_results')
    if not os.path.exists(sp_results_dir):
        os.makedirs(sp_results_dir)

    palette = get_palette(20)
    parsing_preds = []
    scales = np.zeros((num_samples, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    centers = np.zeros((num_samples, 2), dtype=np.int32)
    with torch.no_grad():
        for idx, batch in enumerate(tqdm(testloader)):
            image, meta = batch
            if (len(image.shape) > 4):
                image = image.squeeze()
            im_name = meta['name'][0]
            c = meta['center'].numpy()[0]
            s = meta['scale'].numpy()[0]
            w = meta['width'].numpy()[0]
            h = meta['height'].numpy()[0]
            scales[idx, :] = s
            centers[idx, :] = c
            parsing, logits = multi_scale_testing(model, image.cuda(), crop_size=input_size, flip=args.flip,
                                                  multi_scales=multi_scales)
            print("Parsing:",parsing.shape)
            print("Logits:", logits.shape)
            # if args.save_results:
            if True:
                print("Inside Save_results")
                parsing_result = transform_parsing(parsing, c, s, w, h, input_size)
                parsing_result_path = os.path.join(sp_results_dir, im_name + '.png')
                # print("Parsing Result Path:", parsing_result_path)
                output_im = PILImage.fromarray(np.asarray(parsing_result, dtype=np.uint8))
                output_im.putpalette(palette)
                output_im.save(parsing_result_path)

            parsing_preds.append(parsing)
    assert len(parsing_preds) == num_samples
    mIoU = compute_mean_ioU(parsing_preds, scales, centers, args.num_classes, args.data_dir, input_size)
    print(mIoU)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have successfully ported the model to onnx.
But I am running into issues while converting it to coreml.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluate.py", line 262, in <module>
    main()
  File "evaluate.py", line 240, in main
    parsing, logits = multi_scale_testing(model, image.cuda(), crop_size=input_size, flip=args.flip,
  File "evaluate.py", line 102, in multi_scale_testing
    core_model = ct.convert(scripted_model,inputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=scaled_im.shape)])
  File "/anaconda/envs/schp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/_converters_entry.py", line 176, in convert
    mlmodel = mil_convert(
  File "/anaconda/envs/schp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 128, in mil_convert
    proto = mil_convert_to_proto(model, convert_from, convert_to,
  File "/anaconda/envs/schp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 171, in mil_convert_to_proto
    prog = frontend_converter(model, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/schp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/converter.py", line 85, in __call__
    return load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/schp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/load.py", line 72, in load
    converter = TorchConverter(torchscript, inputs, outputs, cut_at_symbols)
  File "/anaconda/envs/schp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/converter.py", line 142, in __init__
    raw_graph, params_dict = self._expand_and_optimize_ir(self.torchscript)
  File "/anaconda/envs/schp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coremltools/converters/mil/frontend/torch/converter.py", line 250, in _expand_and_optimize_ir
    graph, params = _torch._C._jit_pass_lower_graph(
RuntimeError: Unknown type bool encountered in graph lowering. This type is not supported in ONNX export.
```